# AngularJS: $cookies is empty

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I have a problem with my AngularJS app. I'm trying to get the browser cookies but when I try to access the cookies it's always empty, I've tried it in Safari, Firefox and Chrome. I found this example below that many confirms work but I can't get it to work, see my comments for the output I'm getting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0rc10/angular-1.0.0rc10.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0rc10/angular-cookies-1.0.0rc10.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);
    function CookieCtrl($scope, $cookies) {
      console.log($cookies) // FireBug: Object { }
      $scope.cookieValue = $cookies.text;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="CookieCtrl">

Cookie Value: '{{cookieValue}}' <!-- Cookie Value: '' -->

</body>
</html>
```

I don't get any other errors that indicates that something is wrong.

Thank you in advance, Mattias

Comment: Can you show the code where you SET the cookie to a value?

Comment: I actually don't want to set the cookie myself, I just want to get the cookie that I use to authenticate my Django app so I use it when requesting it. I thought I could login on another tab in my browser and get the cookie from my AngularJS app?

Comment: Did you verify that the cookie exists before trying to access it?  You can generally do this by inspecting the page using developers tools.

Comment: Yes, I use FireBug and in the Cookies tab it says that there are 5 cookies, all from my Django app, these are the ones I want.

Comment: Maybe set up a plunker or jsfiddle?  Seems like your code should work.  Your angular app is in the same domain as the cookies, correct?

Comment: Try [$cookieStore](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.$cookieStore). I had problems with $cookies as well, but $cookieStore was perfect.

Comment: @PhilSandler thanks phil, that was the problem, I had my frontend and my backend on different domains and when I changed it, it worked. is there any way to get it working on different domains though?

Comment: Cookies are specific to domains.  You would have to do some kind of redirect trick to make something like that work.  See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3342225/151084

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments, you can only access cookies from the current domain.  This is not a limitation of Angular; this is simply how cookies work.